# Filter on multi path

Tags: arangodb, graph-traversal, aql

Say, I have a graph with following relationship:

```
app
 ^
 |
 |
tomcat < ------------------
 ^                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
 |                        |
nginx ----> varnish ----> lvs
```

I want to add a filter to the edge between varnish and lvs. How can I do that? Note the p.edges[1].property == value is not what I want. I just want to filter the path nginx->varnish->lvs->tomcat and don't want add filter to the path nginx->tomcat->app.

Comment: How are your collections set up, are these 5 separate collections with edges between them, or is it one collections with a 'vertexType="varnish"' attribute? 
Do you have an example of your query? Just to give an idea of the way to interrogate p.edges and p.vertex.
If you haven't see it, https://docs.arangodb.com/3.0/AQL/Graphs/Traversals.html is a good example of how the traversals are done. If you update your question with info about your query I can help further.

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing the details for your collection setup i can only give seem rough advise. If you could describe more details i can give more specific help.

What you could probably do is the following condition:

`filter !IS_SAME_COLLECTION(p.edges[1]._from) OR p.edges[1].property == value`